# Visual Studio 2017 installer only downloads within the few seconds after a network change

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

So this is a weird one.

I decided to update visual studio, and noticed the installer was CRAWLING. it claims 10 MB/sec download speeds, but only shows an updated download amount of 1 or 2 MB every 20 minutes.

If I disable then re-enable IPV6 on my network adapter, I get a temporary burst where it downloads about 10 MB.

If I turn on my VPN, same result. 10 MB burst, then back to the absolute crawl.

If I change my VPN region and connect to a different server, sometimes I get a burst sometimes I don't.

A quick side note: Certain random actions within the network connections menu in control panel seem to bring my computer to its knees, and hardware is definitely not the bottleneck here. For example, when I try to open the properties for my ethernet adapter, it takes a solid five seconds to load.

Sorry for my random trash diagnostics skills in advance. I'm just trying to get an important assignment done.

Comment: Also: I get 500+ MB/s downloads with my network, and am connected to a gigabit network switch between me and my university's servers, so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Update: Reinstalled network driver. No change. getting **irritated**